# Chart.js uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "@kurkle/color"

Tags: chart.js, bootstrap-5

I'm using Chart.js 4.2 in a laravel project with bootstrap 5.1
The chart works but there's an error on the console that drives me crazy:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "@kurkle/color". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

I'm not installing chart with npm, just referencing with the cdn. Note that the cdn script tag comes without the type attribute, so it return another error:

```
uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module (at chart.min.js:1:1)
```

to fix this you have to add type="module"

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/4.2.1/chart.min.js" integrity="sha512-v3ygConQmvH0QehvQa6gSvTE2VdBZ6wkLOlmK7Mcy2mZ0ZF9saNbbk19QeaoTHdWIEiTlWmrwAL4hS8ElnGFbA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 6):

I ran into this on a Blazor WASM project I'm working on.

The fix for me was to use the UMD bunlde. (There is a pr on the Chart.js repo [here](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/pull/10917) discussing a similar problem)

I am thinking that updating your script tag to use the UMD bundle like so could resolve your issue.

```
<script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/chart.js@4.2.1/dist/chart.umd.js" integrity="sha512-v3ygConQmvH0QehvQa6gSvTE2VdBZ6wkLOlmK7Mcy2mZ0ZF9saNbbk19QeaoTHdWIEiTlWmrwAL4hS8ElnGFbA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on [Chart.js Docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/installation.html), CDNJS and jsDelivr are available for CDN installation.

However, [CDNJS](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/Chart.js) is not working with below error message.

```
Chart.js uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "@kurkle/color"
```

**[jsDelivr](https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/chart.js?path=dist) works very well.**

With jsDelivr, **don't forget to add 'type' attribute in script tag** like below.
(If type attribute is skipped, then you may get another error message.)

```
<script type="module" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@4.3.0/dist/chart.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me (working with Django Templates containing HTML and JS), directly linking the jsDelivr line did not help any. JS did not find the definition of Chart:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Chart is not defined
```

I had to download chart.umd.js and chart.umd.js.map from https://cdnjs.com/libraries/Chart.js , put the two on my own static files server and call them like this:

```
<script src="https://my_server.de/js/chart.umd.js"></script>
```